# Firefox: Offers download when streaming mjpeg

Tags: firefox, stream, mjpeg

I habe an IP camera providing an MJPEG stream. I can play the stream in Chrome and Opera by using an iFrame and setting the src to the streams url:

```
<iframe src="http://user:pwd@domain/video/mjpg.cgi" width="640" height="480">
```

However in Firefox the stream is displayed but after some time FF asks whether to open or to download the file which would be confusing and annoying to the visitor.
Is there a better way to play such stream without using a plugin or addon? I'm not sure whether using an iFrame is a good solution. However when I use an img tag only a still image is displayed and there is no streaming.